# When should i use a for or while loop?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

As someone who is relatively new to the field of programming and has only just started delving into it a few months ago, I find myself struggling to grasp the concept of when and why I should use a 'for' or 'while' loop. Despite my best efforts to seek out a clear and concise answer, I have yet to find a satisfactory explanation that can help me truly understand the nuances of these loops and their applications in programming. Could you provide me with some insight into the appropriate usage of 'for' and 'while' loops in programming, so that I may better understand their significance and effectively apply them in my future projects?

Comment: Basically use a for loop when you want to iterate a know, fixed number of times and a while loop when you want to loop whilst some condition is true (which can be any number of times)

Comment: Adding onto the above comment, for example you can set the while loop condition to true like `while (true) {...code}` which will run infinitely unless there's a break condition in the loop.

Comment: It doesn't matter which type of loop you use in most cases. Prefer the loop that makes it easier to understand what you are doing so it is easier to develop and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple use any loop you feel more comfortable with, generally you should use `for` loop when you want to run for fixed number of time you and use `while` when you want loop to end on specific condition rather than on fix number or time